# Inserting a new record updates LocalDB but not SQL server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm following MVC-Movies tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , and I'm trying to update the records on SQL Server 
and **NOT** on LocalDB .

When I add a new record in my program , for example :

[image]

The DB in SQL Server is not updated , only the LocalDB is .

Here is Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
                           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20140418101450.mdf;
                           Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20140418101450;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


    <add name="MovieDBContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
         AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;
         Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Name of my DB in sql server is : MoviesDB

Thanks

**EDIT**:

Class `Movie` and `MovieDBContext` :

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I changed the connection string to

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
                       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;
                       Initial Catalog=MoviesDB;
                       Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But then I get this :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
>   Line 19:         {
>   Line 20:             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
>   Line 21:         }
>   Line 22:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\X3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MvcMovie\MvcMovie\Controllers\MoviesController.cs    Line: 20

Comment: Can I see the class `Context`?

Comment: @lnanikian: Did you mean class `MovieDBContext` ? I updated the post , thanks .

Comment: But before editing your question, know that LocalDb\V.11 is SQLserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one of your connection strings there are referencing `MoviesDB`.

One is referring to `aspnet-MvcMovie-20140418101450.mdf` and the other `Movies.mdf`.

Your context will use the connection string that matches it's name, unless you override that setting.  So you should modify the `MovieDBContext` connection string to point to your SQL instance instead of the LocalDB

**Edit**

I assume that this is similar to the connection string you actually want, but you should refer to the official [Microsoft Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for other examples.

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MoviesDB;
    Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but then I got an exception , I added it the my original post , under `EDIT 2` . Thanks

Comment: @ron I added a connection string that I think is what you are after, and a link to Microsoft for other possible connection strings.  You should not be using `AttachDbFilename` unless you have a specific file the database is stored in; and in that case, `AttachDbFilename` is Case Sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
    <add name="MovieDBContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
                   AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MoviesDB.mdf;
                   Initial Catalog=MoviesDB;
                   Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```